# Subversion evaluation - most active developers

Tags: svn

I am evaluating a subversion repository. There are about 250 users.
I wanted to know if there is a way to find the users who committed the most during the whole project lifetime.

Is there a program that finds the users who committed the most?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/index.html) and [SVNPlot](http://code.google.com/p/svnplot/) can produce statistics for SVN repositories.

Comment: I will try these two. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to rely on an external program, here is what I use to find out how many lines were written by each users. You may refine the call to `find` to list only the files you're interested in (here only Java files are listed).

```
find . -name *.java | xargs svn annotate | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c
```

To extract only the top 10:

```
find . -name *.java | xargs svn annotate | awk '{print $2}' | sort | head -n 10
```

If your project is big it may take quite some time.

*Note: if your user names contain spaces it may not work as you expect.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a program that will do this for you. It creates a HTML report of who committed the most. It has many features.

Please go to http://www.statsvn.org/ for mor information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a program, have a look at [statsvn](http://www.statsvn.org/).

Also you can have a look at the logs produced by svn.

```
svn log -v
```

You can also limit the results with --limit

```
svn log -v --limit 10
```

have a look at the [logbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html)

Comment: Well it takes a very long time to calculate which user committed the most when looking at the logs. The project started in 1996. The latest revision number is 28270. Number of files: 5326. But thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

If "most" is **commits count** - svn log -q + grep + awk

For 28270 revisions log -q will produce revisions*2+1 strings *only*